# How can I add a message body to a Play2.2 Scala WS GET?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm aware this is unconventional - I'm accessing an API that requires JSON objects posted as a message body for GET requests. Using Play 2.2.2 and `play.api.libs.ws.WS`

I'm attempting to add a message body to the `WSRequestHolder`. The `.post()` method allows this, but the `.get()` method doesn't have such a parameter. I'm looking at using the basic `WSRequest` class instead of the `WSRequestHolder` but not sure of a better way to do this.

Psuedo-code:

`WS.url(url).get(Json.obj("param" -> "value"))`

or

`WS.url(url).setBody(Json.obj("param" -> "value")).get()`

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, roll your own solution.

```
import scala.concurrent.{ Future, Promise }
import play.api.libs.concurrent._
import play.api.libs.iteratee._
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Input._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.http.{ Writeable, ContentTypeOf }
import play.api.libs.ws.WS._
import play.api.libs.ws.{SignatureCalculator, Response}
import com.ning.http.client.Realm.AuthScheme
import com.ning.http.client.PerRequestConfig


class MyRequest(
  url: String,
  headers: Map[String, Seq[String]],
  queryString: Map[String, Seq[String]],
  calc: Option[SignatureCalculator],
  auth: Option[Tuple3[String, String, AuthScheme]],
  followRedirects: Option[Boolean],
  requestTimeout: Option[Int],
  virtualHost: Option[String]

) extends WSRequestHolder(url,headers,queryString,calc,auth,followRedirects,requestTimeout,virtualHost) {

  /**
   * Perform a GET on the request asynchronously with a body.
   */
  def get[T](body: T)(implicit wrt: Writeable[T], ct: ContentTypeOf[T]): Future[Response] = prepare("POST", body).execute

  /**
   * Prepare a request
   * @param method
   * @param body
   * @param wrt
   * @param ct
   * @tparam T
   * @return
   */
  override def prepare[T](method: String, body: T)(implicit wrt: Writeable[T], ct: ContentTypeOf[T]) = {
    val request = new WSRequest(method, auth, calc).setUrl(url)
      .setHeaders(Map("Content-Type" -> Seq(ct.mimeType.getOrElse("text/plain"))) ++ headers)
      .setQueryString(queryString)
      .setBody(wrt.transform(body))
    followRedirects.map(request.setFollowRedirects)
    requestTimeout.map {
      t: Int =>
        val config = new PerRequestConfig()
        config.setRequestTimeoutInMs(t)
        request.setPerRequestConfig(config)
    }
    virtualHost.map {
      v =>
        request.setVirtualHost(v)
    }
    request
  }

}

object MyWS {
  /**
   * Prepare a new request. You can then construct it by chaining calls.
   *
   * @param url the URL to request
   */
  def url(url: String): MyRequest = new MyRequest(url, Map(), Map(), None, None, None, None, None)
}
```